# Is it possible to type numbers to navigate between pages with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to find out whether it is possible using javascript or jQuery to navigate a Wordpress site using your numerical keypad.

For a Flash example, see here: http://elevenfilm.com/ - type in one of the 3 digit numbers to go to that page.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an simple example

HTML

```
<input type="text" />
<div class="page page120">You're on page 120</div>
<div class="page page240">You're on page 240</div>
<div class="page page360">You're on page 360</div>
```

JS

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
   $('.page').hide();
   $('.page'+$(this).val()).show(); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5G8m9/

**Edit**

An ajax call might look like this, depending on your dom structure. You can set a hashtag to show the page in the url there as well.

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://yourblog.com/page/"+$(this).val()
    }).done(function (data) {
        location.hash = $(this).val();
        $('.content').html(data);
    });
});
```

Read about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: For some systems it might be a bit overkill to render 998 hidden pages and and visible one. :)  But the solution would work with ajax as well, so +1

Comment: Hi, thanks that really kinda works and is pretty simple, but I wonder if it's possible to change the URL of the page? I wouldn't know how to use Ajax to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

Sven's edit would work, however a simpler (AJAX free) approach would be:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    var charCode = (96 <= e.which && e.which <= 105) 
        ? e.which - 48 
        : e.which;
    var keyVal = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(keyVal)))
        window.location.href = '/?pageId=' + keyVal
});
```

This will simply redirect the browser to `www.domain.com/?pageId=<NumberPressed>`. Without more information, it is difficult to improve this answer.

EDIT:
Here's a basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kJZ9/)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing that out. I've fixed the error. The bug is related to key characters from the number pad being different to the unicode values they represent.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to @DerFlatulator's answer that allows you to enter a 3 digit number before navigating to the page

```
// keys and loc should be outside the scope of your event handler
// a list of valid keys and their values (0-9 and 0-9 on numberpad)
var keys = { "48": 0, "49": 1, "50": 2, "51": 3, "52": 4, "53": 5, "54": 6, "55": 7, "56": 8, "57": 9, "96": 0, "97": 1, "98": 2, "99": 3, "100": 4, "101": 5, "102": 6, "103": 7, "104": 8, "105": 9 };
// used to hold the page being typed
var loc = []; 

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        if (keys.push(keys[e.keyCode]) == 3) {
            document.location.href = "/?pageId=" & loc.join("");
        }
    }
});
```